# Rule for multiplying of Kronecker-delta-type functions

Tags: replacement

I am trying to introduce a rule of multiplication of entries of a matrix which would have the following property:

```
delta[k,i]*delta[k,j]=delta[k,i]*delta[i,j]
```

and then produce some manipulation with the matrix, for example, calculate its square with respect to this rule. How can I introduce such rule in Mathematica? Of course, the multiplication of entries which have not equal indexes should be usual one.

**UPD** Also `delta` is symmetric. So, I expect instead of

```
In[1]:= Clear[delta];
         delta[k_, i_]*delta[k_, j_] :> delta[k, i]*delta[i, j];
         delta[k_, i_] :> delta[i, k];
         FullSimplify[delta[0, 1] (delta[0, 2] - delta[2, 1])]
Out[33]= delta[0, 1] (delta[0, 2] - delta[2, 1])
```

to get `0` as the answer.

Comment: Is there a problem with just directly using `KroneckerDelta`? If so, can you provide more details about your actual use-case? It's a little unclear exactly what you would need. Something like a replacement `Rule` that looks inside expressions and sees when arguments to `delta`s overlap could work, but we need more info. For instance, are you manipulating symbolic matrices defined with these `delta`s? Are repeated indices implicitly summed over? Etc.

Comment: start with this: `delta[k_, i_]*delta[k_, j_] :> delta[k, i]*delta[i, j]`. ( This may not work if your products are actually embedded in more complicated expressions )

Comment: If you post a specific example, Mathematica input + desired result, it might be easier to make useful suggestions.

Comment: @Dmitri. It seems that you have now asked 8 questions, many of which have excellent answers, but you have yet to accept any of them. While it is the intent of this site (and it is the motivation of the majority of its users) to provide answers to general questions that *many people* (not just the asker) can benefit from, it is still the case that answerers like to be thanked by having an answer that they spent time on accepted. Please consider spending a few seconds to either accept answers that answered your questions or commenting on those answers.

Comment: @march. I can not use `KroneckerDelta`, since my deltas do not need to be 1 or 0 only. I need keep all `delta[k,i]`, however, I'd like to change some products on another ones like it is described above. For example,
`Clear[delta]; delta[k_, i_]*delta[k_, j_] :> delta[k, i]*delta[i, j]; delta[k_, i_] :> delta[i, k];`
should lead to `FullSimplify[delta[0, 1] (delta[0, 2] - delta[2, 1])]` would be equal to 0, but this does not appear.

Comment: @march. Regarding voting for answers: sorry, my fault. Done.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. The question was updated, thanks!

Comment: If you make `delta` orderless then a replacement rule for zero might suffice: `In[1391]:= Clear[delta];
Attributes[delta] = {Orderless};

In[1393]:= 
Expand[delta[0, 1] (delta[0, 2] - delta[2, 1])] /. 
 delta[k_, i_]*delta[k_, j_] - delta[k_, i_]*delta[i_, j_] :> 0

Out[1393]= 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note for your symmetry rule I expect you want to put the indices in some canonical order, here put lowest index first.

```
Expand[delta[0, 1] (delta[0, 2] - delta[2, 1]) ] //. { 
  delta[k_, j_] /; k > j :> delta[j, k] , 
  delta[k_, i_]*delta[k_, j_] :> delta[k, i]*delta[i, j]}
```

> 0

Note expand is needed so the products appear explicitly. This is going to break if you have certain more complicated expressions such as products with more than two deltas.

I expect this can be handled using `Simplify` with `TransformationFunctions` as well. (That would obviate the need for `Expand` and leave expressions alone if no simplification is possible)

Comment: Many thanks! It seems that it works even for some products with more factors.